# Problem in understanding the derivation of the criteria for a set to be order-complete.

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

> 9 Theorem *A set $X$ is order-complete relative to an ordering if and only if each non-void subset which has a lower-bound has an infimum.*
>
> Suppose that $X$ is order-complete and $A$ is non-void subset which has  a lower bound. Let $B$ be the set of all lower bounds of $A\,.$ Then $B$ is non-void and surely every member of the non-void set $A$ is an upper bound for $B\,.$ **Hence, $B$ has a least upper bound, say, $b\,.$** ...

This is excerpted from *General Topology*'s *Orderings* by *John Kelley*; here he proves the theorem that a set is order-complete iff all its non-void subsets which have lower bounds have infimum.

I did stumble a little and couldn't comprehend the statement "***Hence**, $B$ has a least upper bound $b\,.$*"

Is it a trivial conclusion from the fact that all elements included $A$ are upper bounds of $X\,?$

But how does it guarantee that $A$ indeed contains the **lowest** upper bound $b$ of $B\,?$

I couldn't get the author's use of the word "*Hence*"; I'm not seeing it obvious how $A,$ albeit containing elements acting as upper bounds to $B,$ contains the **lowest** upper bound $b$ too.

Could anyone shed light on why the author used "*Hence*" and thus meant that the fact that $A$ contains $b,$ the **lowest** upper bound of $B\,?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paragraph leading up to that theorem, Kelley defines *X* to be order-complete if every non-empty subset of *X* with an upper bound has a least upper bound.

"Hence" is where that definition gets applied: *B* is non-empty (because we know *A* has a lower bound), has an upper bound (any member of *A*, which is non-empty, will do), and is a subset of *X*. So since *X* is order-complete, *B* has a least upper bound *b*.

You're 100% right that *b* might not be contained in *A*! But the rest of the proof doesn't rely on *b* being in *A*. It goes on to show that, because of how we defined *B*, *b* is a lower bound of *A*, and that it's in fact the greatest lower bound of *A*.

(One aspect of the terminology that you might be finding confusing - a set can "have" a least upper bound or greatest lower bound without the l.u.b. or g.l.b being in the set. An example is the interval (0,1): 0 is its greatest lower bound and 1 is its least upper bound, but neither are in the set.)